# "Invalid object name" no matter what I name it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

```
GO
-- Create sproc for returning whether a partner has marked their survey as finished
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckIfFinished
    @pid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @sid INT
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Finished WHERE partner_id=@pid AND survey_id=@sid;
  END 
GO
```

gives

> Invalid object name 'Finished'.

Same as if I changed `Finished` to `MyDatabaseName.dbo.Finished` or `dbo.Finished`.

Makes no sense.

The full context is

```
CREATE TABLE Finished ( 
    partner_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    survey_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (partner_id,survey_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (partner_id) REFERENCES Partners(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (survey_id) REFERENCES Surveys(id)
);

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CheckIfFinished
    @pid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @sid INT
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Finished WHERE partner_id=@pid AND survey_id=@sid;
  END 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateFinishValue (@partner_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
                                    @survey_id INT,
                                    @finished TINYINT)
AS  
    BEGIN
        IF (@finished = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                          FROM Finished 
                                          WHERE Finished.partner_id=@partner_id AND Finished.survey_id=@survey_id))
            INSERT INTO Finished (partner_id,survey_id) VALUES (@survey_id,@partner_id)
        ELSE
            DELETE FROM Finished WHERE partner_id=@partner_id AND survey_id=@survey_id
    END
GO
```

Comment: Are you sure the table `Finished` is created in your database?

Comment: What's the result of this: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Finished'`

Comment: Do you really want to swap values: `(partner_id,survey_id) VALUES (@survey_id,@partner_id)`?

Comment: Is your procedure created in the same database as the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBMS is unable to find this object period.

You can check for the table using this simple query:

```
select * from sys.sysobjects so
where so.name like N'%Finished%'
and so.xtype = N'U'
```

Also the most common causes to your problem are:

- You are looking in the wrong place (server, DB, Schema...)
- You lack permission to look for the object.
- You got a case-sensitive collation issue.
- The objects don't exists (maybe was not created or rolled back)